# Counting self intersection in same shapefile with ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, intersection, advanced-license-level

Is it possible to count the number of intersections in the same linear shapefile with ArcMap 10.2?

[image]

My license level is advanced.

Comment: Try intersecting the shapefile with itself to create points

Comment: Is it actually self-intersections that you’re trying to identify or point locations where three lines meet?

Comment: Dear @PolyGeo It is the points locations where three Lines meet